# Why is mysql is appending data to the end of the list and not the top?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a mock project and is trying to Insert data from another table but the data isn't being inserted to the top.  I've been working with python pandas 'to_csv' to update my table but the data gets inserted from the end.  So now, I created a temp table to try and use the INSERT query to move the data but still getting the same result.  Any suggestion would be great, thanks!

So now, I created a temp table to try and use the INSERT query to move the data but still getting the same result.

insert into orders (order_id)
select order_id from temp

Comment: is there a `sort order`? ... if not, then add it to your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "at the top" in SQL. You have no control over how the data is inserted into the table. If you want the results of your SELECT to be in a certain order, then you need to use an ORDER BY clause.